# Move GridLayout elements to a new row to accommodate smaller screens in Kivy

Tags: android, ios, layout, screen-size, kivy

Lets say I have a GridLayout with four buttons across one row, which looks nice on a tablet. How do I set up my .kv file so that on a smaller screen, like a phone, the four buttons in the single row become two buttons across two rows. Thus fitting on the screen without making the buttons too tiny to see.

I'm still fairly new to Kivy, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this. I just haven't figured it out yet. I've been playing with the API for GridLayout, and tried a few other things, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to setting the GridLayout's `cols` property to 2 if the screen is narrow or 4 if the screen is wider. Here's a short app doing exactly that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<ResponsiveGridLayout>:
    cols: 2 if Window.width < 400 else 4
    Button:
        text: 'button 1'
    Button:
        text: 'button 2'
    Button:
        text: 'button 3'
    Button:
        text: 'button 4'
''')



class ResponsiveGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class GridApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ResponsiveGridLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GridApp().run()
```

You should be able to run this on a desktop and see the number of columns dynamically change as you resize the window. The cutoff is 400 pixels.

The important bit is the line `cols: 2 if Window.width < 400 else 4`. Since everything to the right of a colon is plain python, this returns 2 or 4 depending on the width of Window (imported at the top). And since `cols` is a kivy property, GridLayout can and does monitor it to automatically redo the layout if its value changes.

Edit: And just to be clear, Window.width is also a kivy property, so the kv language automatically binds to it such that `cols` will be updated if Window.width changes. That's why resizing the window works.

Of course there is more you might want to do to make this perfect for your own app. For instance, rather than monitoring the width in pixels you may want to use scale-independent units that map to physical width taking into account screen dpi (see [kivy.metrics](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html)). You may also want to set your GridLayout's height to get larger if it's using two columns/rows, which can be achieved in a similar way.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I realized I could use operators within a .kv file, but I didn't know I could actually do conditionals as well! One question I have; why do you import the Window class in the .kv section and not at the top of the Python file (like GridLayout, Button, etc.)? Also, a bit unrelated, but I see everyone using the Builder method of including kv code in-line with the Python code in all the most recent examples I see. Is this preferred over using a separate .kv file for some practical reason? Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: For the operators, everything on the right of a colon in kv really is just python, you aren't limited by any special syntax. For the import, the kv is separate to the python, so I imported Window in kv because I wanted to reference it there. In contrast, I didn't have any reference to Window in the actual python part, so there was no need to import it there. For the Builder stuff, I only did it that way becuase it's convenient for a short example - and that's probably the same reason people usually do it. Using a separate kv file is generally clearer and easier for any larger project.